# How to send a POST HTTP request in iOS Shortcuts app

Tags: http, post, nfc, shortcut

I am trying to create an automation for my iPhone that will send a POST HTTP request to a local server, running Node-RED on my LAN, when I scan an NFC tag. Can anyone suggest some good resources for this? I found tutorials for having an NFC tag go to a link (if it is pre-programmed with a URL) but in my case, I want to send the NFC tag's ID string as part of the POST request so the remote server knows which tag was scanned and what action to take next. Any ideas?